# How create if in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
    foreach( $top_9_friends as $key => $user )
{

 array_push( $scores,  array( 

  "id" => key($friends_rank_data),
  "likes" => $user['likes'],
  "comments" => $user['comments'],
  "posts" => $user['posts'],
  if(1 == 1) {
         $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . key($friends_rank_data) . '/?fields=gender&access_token=' . $access_token ;
        $contents = file_get_contents( $url );
if( $contents )
{
    $dataa = json_decode( $contents, true );
}
    "sex" => $dataa['data']['0']['gender'],     
    }
 )

 );
}
```

Who can help me how to write correct code,
Where I was wrong
How to enter the correct date

Comment: What is this piece of code **supposed** to do? And what's the output you're getting?

Comment: Why on earth would you want that if statement in your array? Lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to attempt but just separate out how you're building the array.

Also there's no need for **if (1 == 1) {...}**, this just means your always going to do it so why bother?

```
foreach ($top_9_friends as $key => $user) {

    // create array
    $arr = array(
        "id" => key($friends_rank_data),
        "likes" => $user['likes'],
        "comments" => $user['comments'],
        "posts" => $user['posts']
    );

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . key($friends_rank_data) . '/?fields=gender&access_token=' . $access_token;
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($contents) {
        $dataa = json_decode($contents, true);

        // add this array key inside the if statement
        $arr["sex"] = $dataa['data']['0']['gender'];
    }
    array_push($scores, $arr);
}
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100000382928634
            [likes] => 10
            [comments] => 6
            [posts] => 41
            [sex] => 
        )

)

Answer (score 1):

Do the if before the array:

```
foreach( $top_9_friends as $key => $user )
{

    if(1 == 1) {
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . key($friends_rank_data) . '/?fields=gender&access_token=' . $access_token ;
        $contents = file_get_contents( $url );
        if( $contents )
        {
            $dataa = json_decode( $contents, true );
        }
    }

    array_push( $scores,  array( 
        "id" => key($friends_rank_data),
        "likes" => $user['likes'],
        "comments" => $user['comments'],
        "posts" => $user['posts'],
        "sex" => $dataa['data']['0']['gender'],     
     );
 }
```

Comment: The difference between your answer and my answer is that field like `sex` and `url` will be set even if they are null or don't exist. In my solution, unused fields are never set to begin with. All a matter of what the OP is looking for. Good answer.

Comment: @Dutchie432 the OP extracts contents from the URL so i assume it does not have to be set in the array :)

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100000382928634
            [likes] => 10
            [comments] => 6
            [posts] => 41
            [sex] => 
        )

)

Comment: @Andy - I suppose that is a fair assumption, although I'm not sure if it's accurate. Again... Up to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Create an array for each new item and set the values you KNOW first. Then, you can conditionally add values to it based on your `if` statements. Then, once the array item is built, tack it onto the `scores` array.

```
<?php

foreach( $top_9_friends as $key => $user ){

    //Temporary Array with entity proprties
    $new_array_item = array( 
        "id" => key($friends_rank_data),
        "likes" => $user['likes'],
        "comments" => $user['comments'],
        "posts" => $user['posts']
    );

    //Conditionally Add values based on IF logic
    if(1 == 1) {
        $new_array_item['url'] = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.key($friends_rank_data).'/?fields=gender&access_token='.$access_token ;

        $contents = file_get_contents( $new_array_item['url'] );
        if( $contents ) {
            $dataa = json_decode( $contents, true );
            $new_array_item['sex'] = $dataa['data']['0']['gender'];
        }
    }
    //Tack Temporary Array Item onto $scores
    $scores[]=$new_array_item;
}

?>
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in: $contents = file_get_contents( $url );

Comment: My mistake. There was a typo - try the new code. Thanks.